# Why do Vaadin gwt input fields have no id and no name?

Tags: html, gwt, vaadin

I was wondering why Vaadin GWT components don't have an id or a name? I am asking, because I want to reference them using external Java-Script, e.g. with document.getElementById('foo').

Does anyone know an easy why to add those attributes?

Thanks,
Stephanie

Answer (score 1):

You can set an id for a Vaadin component by using setDebugId:

```
button.setDebugId("myDebugId");
```

As of vaadin 7 setDebugId is deprecated and:

```
button.setId("myDebugId");
```

should be used

Comment: will this debugId still be avaiable, when you set production mode to false?

Comment: Is there a technical reason why they are not there?

Comment: @nexus Those debugIds are always added to elements.

Comment: @Henri: as the name suggests (setDebugId) it is for debugging. I was wondering why the Vaadin developers don't want to have the id or the name in their productive programms.